# File modified time result does not match up with current time

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a program in which I need to compare the time of which a file was modified to the current time. If a file has not been modified for a certain amount of time, then it is considered "old" and a process is killed.

However, when I get my current time and my modification time they do not return comparable results. They appear to come back in the same format, but the difference between the two doesn't make sense. I am assuming that this has something to do with the timezone or perhaps how I am returning the times. Tried doing some searching but haven't been able to find anything that has fixed my issue.

Get modified time:

```
time_t getMod(const char *file){
    struct stat attrib;
    if (stat(file, &attrib) == -1) {
        perror(file);
        exit(1);
    }
    return attrib.st_mtime;
}
```

Get current time and compare:

```
while(loop == 1){
    printf ("Sleeping..\n");
    sleep(numSleep); //Sleep
    printf ("Awake..\n");

    curTime = time(0); //Current time
    modTime = getMod(argv[fileIndex]); //Modified time

    printf ("Current time: %d\n", curTime);
    printf ("Modified time: %d\n", modTime);

    seconds = curTime - modTime;
    printf ("Seconds: %d\n", seconds);
    if(seconds > numSleep){
        kill(pid, SIGKILL); 
    }
}
```

An example of the output I have been getting when I modify the file while sleep:

```
Current time: 1433371851
Modified time: 1433374890
```

Comment: Is the file located on NFS or other network mount?

Comment: The file is specified in the arguments, from the console (I run the program using ./a.out test.txt). The file is in the same folder as the program itself as well.

Comment: Your time code looks ok. And the difference is almost 1 hr in future. So my guess is - modification is done on a server which is in a different timezone.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you have any suggestions on how to work through this? I've tried using localtime and some other timezone tutorials but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost certainly has to be a file stored on a different server.  The st_mtime field is updated by the server using the server's clock even if the file was modified remotely from a client machine.   When the clocks differ on the client and server, this can lead to apparent discrepencies for modification times.

Either the server or the host where you are running the program has the clock set wrong.

The values returned either by time() or stat should be irrespective of timezones as they should be the standard linux Epoch (which is the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC Jan 1 1970 -with some minor caveats)   So differences in timezone settings shouldn't account for it.

You can do a simple test from the host where you are running the program while you are in the same directory that you are using now:

```
 echo x > file; ls -l file;  date
```

The times reported by ls and date should very closely agree.  If not, the clock is set wrong on the client or server.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, the lab computer I'm using is about an hour and 2 minutes off. Adding 3480 to my current time "fixes" the issue.
Thanks!